# Adaptive Card Action.ShowCard Button Focus Out Issue

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

### Target Platform

- NodeJS

```
"botbuilder": "^3.14.0",
"botbuilder-teams": "^0.2.1",
```

Though I believe it should be same for bot written in Python

### Target Application

- Webchat (https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js)

### Problem Description

It is hard to explain the issue in words so attaching a gif image for better explanation.

- All five buttons as shown in the gif (in the beginning) are choice buttons and each of them displays some of the data. Similary **DQ sheet** button also shows adaptive cards in carousel. The last adaptive card  (titled Deal Qualification Sheet - 3) in carousel used **Action.ShowCard** (expandable button) to show more data (around 00:10 seconds of gif). i,e **Opportunity Assessment** is actually an **Action.ShowCard**
- We noticed that when the carousel (left-right arrow) or **Action.ShowCard** is clicked it is making other choice buttons available in the space non-reachable at first click. As it is shown in the gif (around 00:17 seconds) when **Sales strategy** choice button is clicked, it directly jumped back to the Carousel where adaptive cards were shown.

**Note:** We noticed that the adaptive cards having **Action.ShowCard** is causing this issue more frequently. Which means that showing just a single adaptive card (not necessarily in carousel layout) with **Action.ShowCard** buttons is enough to reproduce this issue. Though I'm also attaching few sample adaptive cards.

### Issue Screenshot

[image]

#### Video Link:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3635655/121223765-7c917a80-c8a5-11eb-8dda-a029b211a4bc.mp4

#### I raised this as an [issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/5974) as well but didn't get any response.

### Card JSON

**Note:** The issue is only appearing for channel = `webchat`. Couldn't replicate it using emulator. Below is equivalent JSON response received using Bot Framework Emulator.

#### Sample Code

[emulator_response_json.txt](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/files/6618435/emulator_response_json.txt)

## Version of SDK

### 3.14.0

Comment: This appears to be a Web Chat problem and not an Adaptive Cards problem. That might explain why you didn't get a response in the Adaptive Cards repo. At any rate, even with the gif/video it's not clear what you're saying the problem is. You haven't given any repro steps, and the way you're reproducing it yourself appears to be extremely complicated with too many moving parts. If you'd like help with this, could you try to create a minimal example in order to demonstrate the problem with the smallest card possible? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @KyleDelaney: 
**Problem:**
When **Sales Strategy** choice button is clicked after interacting with **Adaptive Cards** (in carousel layout layout), it didn't work rather **It jumped back again to the Carousel** (This is captured in the Video around 00:18 seconds. Same thing happened around 00:35 seconds when **DQ Sheet** choice button was clicked.)  It is very difficult to give you a sample bot flow as it requires bot logic as well as the design. May be I can give you a public URL which will open the bot and will go to this step directly. I'll come back..

Comment: Are you able to give me a public URL yet?